# Binomial Expansion Distinct Terms

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion

I have been stuck on a problem and I was wondering if someone could help me solve it. I am asked to find the number of distinct terms in the multivariate polynomial $f=(a+2b-c+3d)^{17}$ in which three of the powers of these terms are precisely even, and then determine the number of terms in which at least two of powers are greater than $6$. Does anyone know how to approach this problem? Is there is a formula that can be used to calculate these numbers?

Comment: This is a [Multinomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) problem.

Comment: Thanks for the information. How do I now go about determining the at least part of this problem? I am unsure how to count these quantities. I have the formula for computing the term, but I am having a difficult time utilizing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have to select $17$ times one element from $\{a,b,c,d\}$.

- Two of these elements have to occur at least $7$ times. We select exemplarily $a,b$ and consider
  \begin{align*}
  a^7(2b)^7(a+2b-c+3d)^3\tag{1}
  \end{align*}
- Since precisely three elements have to be even powers it follows from (1) that the only possible solutions from $(a+2b-c+3d)^3$ in this configuration are
  \begin{align*}
  a^8(2b)^8c\qquad \text{and}\qquad a^8(2b)^8(3d)\tag{2}
  \end{align*}

We observe from (1) we can select $\binom{4}{2}=6$ tuples from $\{a,b,c,d\}$ as we did with $a$ and $b$ . Then we have two ways to find valid choices according to (2).  We conclude the number of distinct terms with the wanted properties is
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{2\binom{4}{2}=12}
\end{align*}

Comment: Read the question again.